# Next.js: How to clear browser history with Next Router?

Tags: next.js, browser-history, next-router

I created a wrapper for the pages which will bounce unauthenticated users to the login page.

PrivateRoute Wrapper:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useUser } from '../../lib/hooks'
import Login from '../../pages/login'

const withAuth = Component => {
  const Auth = (props) => {
    const { user } = useUser();
    const router = useRouter();

    if (user === null && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      return (
        <Login />
      );
    }


    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  };

  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    Auth.getInitialProps = Component.getInitialProps;
  }

  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

That works \o/, However I noticed a behavior when I log out, using `Router.push('/',)`, to return the user to the homepage the back button contains the state of previous routes, I want the state to reset, as a user who is **not** authenticated should have an experience as if they're starting from scratch...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't clear the browser's history stack, you can only navigate through it. See MDN `Window.history` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history#notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `Router.replace('/any-route')` and the user will not be able to go back with back button

Comment: `router.replace` merely prevents a new item in the history stack; it does not clear out the entire stack like the question asks. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#routerreplace) say that replace `will prevent adding a new URL entry into the history stack`. So if there are 10 items in the history, calling replace will merely update the last item in the history and the previous 9 items will still remain. The user will absolutely be able to `go back with the back button` if those previous 9 items remain.